# How to add date column in table in date format eg dd:mm:yy NOT as String

Tags: hiveql

I have to insert one new column in hive table which shows date of loading data. This may be in format dd:mm:yy or say yy:mm:dd format. I don't want default String.

Answer (score 0):

We are using hive 2.1, date format in hive is yyyy-MM-dd, so you cannot have date column with other format, either date data type with default format
or string column with required date format.

```
hive> create table date1 (c1 date);
hive> insert into date1 ('2019-02-15');
hive> insert into date1 (c1) select current_date();

hive> select * from date1;
OK
2019-02-15
2019-02-15
Time taken: 0.134 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

It's preferred to have string data type in table rather than date column.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! It worked. If we want to sort by date and if column is in String format then it worn't work unless we use cast() to date. Why is't preferred to store as String ?

Comment: Question is different from what you mentioned in comment

Comment: if you want dates in different format then store as string, and then you can format it to date using date functions